# Angular @Output not working

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-components

Trying to do child to parent communication with @Output event emitter but is no working 
here is the child component

```
import { Component, OnInit, Output, Input, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-emiter',
  templateUrl: './emiter.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./emiter.component.css']
})
export class EmiterComponent implements OnInit {

@Output() emitor: EventEmitter<any>
  constructor() { this.emitor = new EventEmitter()}

   touchHere(){this.emitor.emit('Should Work');
   console.log('<><><><>',this.emitor) // this comes empty
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

this is the html template

```
<p>
<button (click)=" touchHere()" class="btn btn-success btn-block">touch</button>
</p>
```

The console.log inside the touchHere it shows nothing
even if I put this inside the parent component it show nothing as well
parent component

```
 import { Component , OnInit} from '@angular/core';
// service I use for other stuff//
    import { SenderService } from './sender.service';
// I dont know if I have to import this but did it just in case
    import { EmiterComponent } from './emiter/emiter.component'

@Component({
      selector: 'app-root',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
    })
    export class AppComponent {
      title = 'app';
      user: any;
      touchThis(message: string) {
        console.log('Not working: ${message}');
      }
        constructor(private mySessionService: SenderService) { }
    }
```

and here is the html template

```
<div>
  <app-emiter>(touchHere)='touchThis($event)'</app-emiter>
</div>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Parent component template:

```
  <app-emitor (emitor)='touchThis($event)'></app-emiter>
```

In parent template @Output should be 'called', not the child method.

Also, see: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-listens-for-child-event

Comment: @Output decorator is in child because the child will emit an event. That event should be console.logged but is showing empty. In the parent I put the event handler to receive that emitted event but in the child I should be seeing something when console.log

Comment: Of course @Output it is in child component and you should call it in parent template. In your code you are calling the child method (touchHere) instead

Comment: this is the parent template <div>
  <app-emiter>(touchHere)='touchThis($event)'</app-emiter>
</div> I am calling touchHere that is inside the selector that is in the parent component. But in any case if I console.log in the child I should see something but I am not

Comment: It is an old question but thanks to Vega .. I had an error in the way I was writing the code

Comment: Glad you found a solution :)

Answer (score 2):

Here’s an example of how we write a component that has outputs:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'single-component',
  template: `<button (click)="liked()">Like it?</button>`
 })
 class SingleComponent {
 @Output() putRingOnIt: EventEmitter<string>;

 constructor() {
 this.putRingOnIt = new EventEmitter();
 }

 liked(): void {
 this.putRingOnIt.emit("oh oh oh");
 }
}
```

Notice that we did all three steps: 1. specified outputs, 2. created an EventEmitter that we attached
to the output property putRingOnIt and 3. Emitted an event when liked is called.

If we wanted to use this output in a parent component we could do something like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'club',
  template: `
    <div>
      <single-component
        (putRingOnIt)="ringWasPlaced($event)"
        ></single-component>
    </div>`
})
class ClubComponent {
ringWasPlaced(message: string) { console.log(`Put your hands up: ${message}`);
} }
// logged -> "Put your hands up: oh oh oh"
```

Again, notice that:

- putRingOnIt comes from the outputs of SingleComponent
- ringWasPlaced is a function on the ClubComponent
- $event contains the thing that wasemitted, in this case a string

Answer (score 0):

```
 <app-emiter (emitor)="touchThis($event)" ></app-emiter>
```

By using `@Output()` you should apply the event you need to emit in the directive of the emitter component.Adding the name of the variable to the the directive and but the emitted over function inside the quotation passing the `$event`.

Answer (score 0):

touchHere() is the method from which you are binding some value to emit with your EventEmitter. And your EventEmitter is 'emitor'.

So your code will work if you simply do the below:

```
<app-emiter (emitor)='touchThis($event)'></app-emiter>
```